Setting up Appconfig Agent cross account retrieval
I am trying to setup app config agent on EC2 using appconfig agent EC2 guide. I need to setup Multi-account retrieval and I am following  Multi-account retrieval Guide.
But When I am trying to hit 'curl http://localhost:2772/applications/${cross-account-application}/env...." I am getting {"Message":"User: arn:aws:sts::${main-account}:assumed-role/ProfileRole-DO-NOT-DELETE/i-04eb5dd03a1282af7 is not authorized to perform: appconfig:StartConfigurationSession on resource: arn:aws:appconfig:ap-south-1:${main-account}:application/${cross-account-application}/env.... because no identity-based policy allows the appconfig:StartConfigurationSession action"}
This is my appconfig config file
"""
Environment=LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
Environment=LOG_PATH=/var/log/AppConifg_Agent.log
Environment=SERVICE_REGION=ap-south-1
Environment=MANIFEST="{
"ISNPAutoConfigurationManager-Beta:*:*": {
    "credentials": {
        "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::${main-account}:${role-with-sts-assume-role}",
        "roleExternalId": "00e3dw-2ewecxwcef-b0f-c422b54d0aac",
        "roleSessionName": "AWSAppConfigAgent",
        "credentialsDuration": "2h"
    }
  }
}"
"""

How to tell appconfig agent to fetch config from vendor account and not main account?
